# ZF2 Form Collections - filtering empty records

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm trying to work out how to filter empty records from a form collection. With my application I have 2 entities, `Competition` and `League`. A competition may have zero or more Leagues.

So I create a Competition form (`CompetitionForm`), a Competition fieldset (`CompetitionFieldset`) and a League fieldset (`LeagueFieldset`).

The `CompetitionFieldset` is added to the `CompetitionForm`, and the `CompetitionFieldset` uses `Zend\Form\Element\Collection` to allow the user to add 1 or more Leagues. I've added the current code for each class below.

By default, I want to display input fields for 3 leagues within a competition, so within the `CompetitionFieldset`, when I add the `Zend\Form\Element\Collection` item, I set the count option to 3.

But if a user doesn't supply any data for the leagues, I want to ignore them. At present, three empty associated leagues are created within my database.

If I set an `InputFilter` on the `LeagueFieldset` to make the `name` field required for example, then the form won't validate.

I should maybe also mention that I'm using Doctrine2 to model my entities and hydrate my forms etc.

I'm sure I could make it work with some additional code on my models, or even in my Controller where I process the form, but I'm sure there is a neater solution maybe using Filters.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

```
:wq
familymangreg
```

My CompetitionForm

```
use Kickoff\Form\AbstractAdminForm;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;

class CompetitionForm extends AbstractAdminForm
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($objectManager, 'competition-form');

        $fieldset = new CompetitionFieldset($objectManager);
        $fieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($fieldset);

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Submit',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

My CompetitionFieldset

```
use Kickoff\Form\AbstractFieldset;
use Kickoff\Model\Entities\Competition;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;

class CompetitionFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($objectManager,'Competition');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->objectManager,'Kickoff\Model\Entities\Competition'))
            ->setObject(new Competition());

        $this->setLabel('Competition');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Competition name (e.g. Premier League)',                
            ),
            'attirbutes' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'long_name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Competition long name (e.g. Barclays Premier League)',
            ),
            'attirbutes' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        ));

        $leagueFieldset = new LeagueFieldset($objectManager);
        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name' => 'leagues',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Leagues',
                'count' => 3,
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'target_element' => $leagueFieldset,
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

My LeagueFieldset

```
use Kickoff\Form\AbstractFieldset;
use Kickoff\Model\Entities\League;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class LeagueFieldset extends AbstractFieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($objectManager,'League');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->objectManager,'Kickoff\Model\Entities\League'))
            ->setObject(new League());

        $this->setLabel('League');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'League name (e.g. First Qualifying Round)',
            ),
            'attirbutes' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'long_name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'League long name (e.g. UEFA Champions League First Qualifying Round)',
            ),
            'attirbutes' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'name' => array(
                'required' => true,
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: You could write a method in the League model that checks if the fields are empty then when iterating over the League entries right before submitting them to the DB run that check. If its empty, don't save it. Maybe not the most efficient place to put the check since the blank fieldsets will still have validators and filters ran on it but it would work.

Comment: could you post the relevant code in your controller and the association in your doctrine entities?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get data from request before you pass it to EntityManager, that's for sure. Just add your own validation to filter empty records. You can also provide javascript filters that will catch submit form event and delete empty fields before submitting it.